# How to link seat plan relation to individual bookings

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have this problem, a concert house where customers book seats (A1, A2, n). Let's say I have this relations:

```
Philharmony
  concertId
  A1
  A2
  ..
  n

Booking
  bookingId
  concertId (foreign key)
  Seat1
  Seat2
  ..
  Seat10
```

Now how would you ensure referencial integrity here? In above example the application will have to update 2 tables for each booking operation. Furthermore, what if I have 5 concert halls instead of one?

Comment: Why would you have to update 2 tables?  Wouldn't you just add a row to the *Booking* table?

Comment: If you only add a new tuple to the Booking table, how would other Bookings know of the seats booked already? There has to be a central seat store (Philharmony relation) for that particular concert (conertId) imho.

Comment: Or maybe if I integrate all seats inside each Booking relation and add a contraint like A <- SELECT Booking booking_id = n /// B <- SELECT Booking booking_id = m /// A difference B is A ?

Comment: Is Philharmony a table? Are A1, A2, etc, columns in that table?